# XSLT vs Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xslt, repeater

I have huge amount of data say 4000 records to be displayed. Currently I'm displaying them using repeater which I felt like lightweight control over others. I thought of designing my new application using xslt to bind html content. Will this approach enhance the performance of my application ?

Comment: You should consider that you may need to provide pageing in the future. In general I'd think any composite control (like repeater) is more optimized than implementing this yourself in xslt.